# Timestamp: how to identify the time when a CPU commend arrives at the sound card?

Tags: android, timestamp, alsa

how to identify the time when a CPU commend arrives
at the sound card and triggers a sound play, by inspecting the audio
driver"?

I have reached https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap.git/+/android-omap-3.0/sound/, but there are lots of documents and codes in it. So I cannot find the exact location of the codes related to the time needed from CPU to sound card.

Then I also think that the codes about this timestamp should be in the "https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap.git/+/android-omap-3.0/Documentation/sound/alsa/". Same question- so many documents in it, I have no idea where the codes are supposed to be...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the `trigger` callback of the platform driver of whatever audio DMA controller it is that you're using.
In your case, look into `sound/soc/omap/omap-mcbsp.c` and `omap-pcm.c`.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the trigger in sound/soc/omap/omap-mcbsp.c. I am wondering that if I can add something at the start of "trigger" to record the start time and then add something before the "break" of "case SNDRV_PCM_TRIGGER_PAUSE_RELEASE" to record the end time. Is the difference between the two recorded time is the delay between the time when the playing command is issued and the time actually the audio device starts? The link of the segment is in https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap.git/+/android-omap-3.0/sound/soc/omap/omap-mcbsp.c    Thank you!

Comment: That trigger is when the device is actually started, but the playing command itself is not seen by the driver.

Comment: Another question, what is the main difference and relationship of the triggers between the omap-mcbsp.c and omap-pcm.c?